# how to count non zero values in each category

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, across

this is my data

```
df <- structure(list(team_3_F = c("team ", "team ", "site", "site", 
"team ", "team ", "newyorkish", "newyorkish", "team ", "team ", 
"newyorkish", "newyorkish", "browingal ", "browingal ", "site", 
"site", "browingal ", "browingal ", "browingal ", "browingal ", 
"team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", "team ", 
"team ", "team ", "team ", "site", "site", "browingal ", "browingal ", 
"browingal ", "browingal ", "browingal ", "browingal ", "browingal ", 
"browingal ", "browingal ", "browingal ", "team ", "team ", "team ", 
"team ", "newyorkish", "newyorkish", "browingal ", "browingal ", 
"newyorkish", "newyorkish", "browingal ", "browingal ", "team ", 
"team ", "browingal ", "browingal ", "team "), name = c("AAA_US", 
"BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", 
"AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", 
"BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", 
"AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", 
"BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", 
"AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", 
"BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", 
"AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", "BBB_US", "AAA_US", 
"BBB_US", "AAA_US"), value = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 1L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 45L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 88L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 19L)), row.names = c(NA, -59L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to identify the non-zero per each group and so I should have an output like this

```
browingal   AAA_US  1
browingal   BBB_US  7
newyorkish  AAA_US  4
newyorkish  BBB_US  0
site        AAA_US  0
site        BBB_US  1
team        AAA_US  6
team        BBB_US  0
```

I tried to categorize it but I could not figure it out

```
df %>% group_by(name) %>% summarise_each(function(x) min(x[x != 0]),value)
```

Comment: You can check ```Rfast2::colGroup```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution. As per documentation:

> `mutate_each()` and `summarise_each` are deprecated in favor of new
> `across` function that works with `summarize()` & `mutate()`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(team_3_F, name) %>%
  summarise(across(value, ~ sum(.x != 0)))

# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   team_3_F [4]
  team_3_F     name   value
  <chr>        <chr>  <int>
1 "browingal " AAA_US     1
2 "browingal " BBB_US     7
3 "newyorkish" AAA_US     4
4 "newyorkish" BBB_US     0
5 "site"       AAA_US     0
6 "site"       BBB_US     1
7 "team "      AAA_US     6
8 "team "      BBB_US     0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)

dt[, sum(value != 0), by = c("team_3_F", "name")]

     team_3_F   name V1
1:      team  AAA_US  6
2:      team  BBB_US  0
3:       site AAA_US  0
4:       site BBB_US  1
5: newyorkish AAA_US  4
6: newyorkish BBB_US  0
7: browingal  AAA_US  1
8: browingal  BBB_US  7
```